# Lazy Evaluation - Java

Tags: java, lazy-evaluation

Can somebody make an detailed explanation (and i mean really detailed, im dumb) of lazy evaluation in java and maybe also explain what is meant with eager evaluation?

Why is this bringing a runtime-error when b = 0?

```
if (a/b < 2 && b>0)//execute something
```

And why does this not give one?

```
if (b>0 && a/b < 2)//execute something
```

Both should be cases of lazy evaluation, but i just dont get why one is working and the other one isn't.

Comment: They're evaluated left-to-right. That's all the detail you really need, and the same is true of virtually every language.

Comment: where comes lazy evaluation comes into the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a/b < 2`
gets a Division by zero error wich will be executed in the first example.

In the second example `b>0` will be evaluated first , is false, so the second part will not be evaluated, because the first part is false and the complete result can't be true